# How to set x limits on varImpPlot

Tags: r, plot, random-forest

How can I change the `x` limits of a plot produced by `varImpPlot` from the `randomForest` package?

If I try

```
set.seed(4543)
data(mtcars)
mtcars.rf <- randomForest(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars, ntree=1000, keep.forest=FALSE,
                      importance=TRUE)
varImpPlot(mtcars.rf, scale=FALSE, type=1, xlim=c(0,15))
```

I get the following error:

> Error in dotchart(imp[ord, i], xlab = colnames(imp)[i], ylab = "", main = if (nmeas ==  : formal argument "xlim" matched by multiple actual arguments".

This is because `varImpPlot` defines its own `x` limits, I think, but how could I get around this if I wanted to set the x limits myself (perhaps for consistency across plots)?

Comment: I have tended away from using varimpplot, towards using dotchart, dotplot {lattice} or geom_dotplot {ggplot2} to have more versatile control over plots. You can extract the values to plot using importance(mtcars.rf). Of course, importance can also be shown quite nicely using bars instead of dots, though this is less common. This lends itself well to grouped bar plots if you are comparing importance between different RFs.

Comment: Having said this, I think the reason xlim does not work is because varimp plot by default creates 2 dot charts for different measures of importance. So it does not know which axis to apply limits to. Try setting type=1 or type=2, and limits should work

Comment: I had tried setting type=1, and I still got the same error. Ended up using your first suggestion and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I extracted the values using `importance()` (thanks to the suggestion from @dww)

```
impToPlot <- importance(mtcars.rf, scale=FALSE)
```

Then I plotted them using `dotchart()`, which allowed me to manually set the x limits (and any other plot features I'd like)

```
dotchart(sort(impToPlot[,1]), xlim=c(0,15), xlab="%IncMSE")
```

[image: dotchart of variable importance with manual x axis]